# Laravel Contract gives 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've made a Contract interface and an Eloquent Repository for my application but I'm getting a 500 error when I try to use it.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the way it is registered. To do this with a service provider which has the following `register` method:

```
/**
* Register service provider bindings
*/
public function registerBindings() {
    $this->app->bind(
        \App\Repositories\Backend\EventContract::class,
        \App\Repositories\Backend\EloquentEventRepository::class
    );
}
```

I then use the contract as follows in my controller:

class EventController extends Controller
{

```
/**
 * @var EventContract
 */
protected $events;

/**
 * EventController constructor.
 * @param EventContract $events
 */
public function __construct(EventContract $events)
{
    $this->events = $events;
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{

    return view('backend.events.index')
                ->withEvents($this->events->getEventsPaginated(25, 1));
```

When I load the page with the 500 error there's no entry in the Laravel logs or the Nginx logs (I use Homestead with Vagrant).

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Found some logs!

```
2016/02/17 09:47:52 [error] 1868#0: *331 FastCGI sent in stderr: "inate\Container\Container->make() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:674
PHP message: PHP 478. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:633
PHP message: PHP 479. Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779
PHP message: PHP 480. Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:808
PHP message: PHP 481. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:853
PHP message: PHP 482. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:674
PHP message: PHP 483. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:633
PHP message: PHP 484. Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:735
PHP message: PHP 485. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:230
PHP message: PHP 486. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:674
PHP message: PHP 487. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:633
PHP message: PHP 488. Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies() /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779
PHP message: PHP 489. Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass() /home
```

Comment: Have you tried the PHP error_log too?

Comment: @AndrewKhan Couldn't find those in `/var/log`. Are they somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

May be stupid pointers, but no harm checking:

1. Double check the namespace in respective files i.e. EventContract
   and EloquentEventRepository class files.
2. Check if you have imported the namespace in the EventController if
   not using full path
3. After
   registering service provider did you run composer dump-autoload -o

Try using chrome devtools to see the response if debug is on

Comment: Tried all of those things but no luck :( Noticed in the reponse headers that Transfer-Encoding is `chunked` though? Thought that was a bit odd

Comment: @Roemer Bakker -Transfer-Encoding:chunked is a way to increase the efficiency of sending data by apache or any webserver. This is especially the case when the request is HTTP/1.1 or gzip is enabled. I don't think that it could be tripping the server. I am not too sure though. It would be difficult to nail the source of error without stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry not able to identify the exact source of error. But looking at the stacktrace snippet a couple of things to check. 1. Do you have any special character in your .env file? 2. Do you actually have a .env file? 3. Did you set the application key?. 4. Does your PSR-4 autoload in composer.json have the correct namespace and path?

Comment: Is your custom service provider added to the providers array without any typo and with correct full path in the providers array of the config/app.php?